# Best practice use of import instead of require with functions and reused variables

Tags: node.js

What is the best practice of using `import` instead of `require` of called functions and reused variables - For example how should these `require`-lines look like as `import`?

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: Asking for best practices is asking for opinions and off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to import the required functions and modules and use them in a next step:

```
import express from 'express';
import {createServer} from 'http';
import socketIo from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

`import` and `require` both of them are good to use. But by convention in node almost use require over than import.

If you are very fond of ES6, then you can use import and other es6 features. But one thing should bear in mind that, when you are using es6, it is a good practice to bundle your code with bundeller (like webpack,babel)

Comment: _"But by convention in node almost use require over than import."_ Which convention is it? Do you have a link? Why is it good practice to bundle ES6 Node.js code and why isn't it good practice to do the same with CommonJS modules?

Comment: For your first question - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-node-js-require-and-es6-import-and-export see the end note

Comment: For your second question - https://medium.com/@shayan.ta69/how-to-build-node-js-application-933e006d7b86 see this and this https://geekflare.com/node-js-bundler-and-build-tools/ .

Comment: You should know that geeksforgeeks is considered a bad resource, because it contains many wrong information, bad practices and outdated code. It's a blog written by some hobby coders. Anybody can write a post there and most posts are written by inexperienced students. The same for medium or geekflare. The NodeJs team considers ES6 as first level module system for NodeJs.

Comment: You didn't answer why you would bundle ES6 modules but not CommonJs modules.

Comment: I've read your first link and can't find why you would consider CJS better than ES6. Can you quote?